# Dynamically added gameobject didn't show on canvas

Tags: unity, initialization

I have a canvas with a `Scroll View` in it.

When I manually add a prefab under the `Content`, it showed up nicely.

But when I add it through the following code, nothing showed up!

```
GameObject RaceGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Race"));
RaceGO.transform.SetParent(Content);
```

Could somebody please tell me why!?

Much appreciated!

PS. I had checked that the gameobject IS in the content! I just can't see it!

Comment: Why can't you see it? Is it positioned behind something else, or way off-camera to the left or right, or scaled/rotated so as to be invisible to the camera?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out! I had used `Grid Layout Group` and `Content Size Fitter` in the `Content`, so it should line it up nicely for me. I had tested it true by manually add prefabs to the content. But when I add it through the code, it was invisible! I had tried to add more prefab into it, and it showed up "after" the invisible thing! So it was there! I just can't see it!

Comment: Have you looked for it in the scene view? Have you taken a look at its transform parameters to see if any are amiss? Have you tried SetParent(Content, false)?

Comment: It worked! Sorry for my lack of understanding about `SetParent`! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the problem was calling `SetParent` without the second argment.

`RaceGo.SetParent(Content)` is equivalent to `RaceGo.SetParent(Content, true)`, saying you want `worldPositonStays` to be true. That is, it's asking Unity to adjust the object's local transformation after parenting to keep the object in the same place in the world that it was before parenting.

So your prefab was probably spawned somewhere like the world origin - which might be a long way from your UI canvas - and parenting it with `worldPositionStays` set to true will try to keep it there after re-parenting, meaning it's likely well outside the screen in UI space.

By explicitly making this argument false, `RaceGo.SetParent(Content, false)`, you're telling Unity not to try to keep the object where it is. So it keeps its local transformation, just relative to the new parent now. This likely keeps it much closer to where you actually want it. You can inspect its transform properties to see if you still need to nudge it into place after parenting.